# Comparison of I-F, Br-F, and Cl-F bond strengths

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond, halides

From *Chemistry of the Elements* by Greenwood and Earnshaw [1, p. 833]:

> [image: The mean bond energy for X-F]
>   **Figure 17.9** Mean bond energies of halogen fluorides.

This shows the mean bond energy for $\ce{X-F}$, where $\ce{X}$ is a halogen. I have several questions:

1. Why is the $\ce{X-F}$ bond in $\ce{XF}$ stronger than that in $\ce{XF3}$ or $\ce{XF5}$? I think it is because the $\ce{XF}$ bond has bond order 1, but $\ce{XF3}$ and $\ce{XF4}$ both have 3c-4e bonds. However, I am not too sure about this explanation. It also doesn't really explain why $\ce{XF5}$ is weaker than $\ce{XF3}$.
2. Why is the order of bond enthalpy generally $\ce{IF} > \ce{BrF} > \ce{ClF}$? I thought it would be the reverse, because smaller atoms would be able to have better atomic orbital overlap.

#### References

1. Greenwood, N. N.; Earnshaw, A. *Chemistry of the Elements*, 2nd ed.; Butterworth-Heinemann: Oxford; Boston, **1997**. ISBN 978-0-7506-3365-9.

Comment: When appending an illustration from a third-party source, make sure it's readable and the source is properly cited (see my edit; also feel free to use it as an example for your future posts).

Comment: For me this graph is very logical and provides insight into *actual properties* of these compounds. For example it's generally more difficult to get higher and higher oxidation states of halogens.